# Third-party modules installed with Composer don't have their version in the .info.yml file

Tags: 8, composer

I have a project installed by composer, everything working perfectly, except when i run `composer install` contrib module installed successfully in `web/modules/contrib` but none of the modules `.info.yml` contain something like:

```
# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2016-06-09
version: '8.x-3.0-alpha2'
core: '8.x'
project: 'MODULENAME'
datestamp: 1465505348
```

Issue is i don't see module needs update in *admin/reports/updates*
and when i run `drush ups` i get 
[image]

Or even `composer show` i get 
[image]

Even on *admin/modules* i can't see the module version 
[image]
Like the following picture from another project 
[image]

And i can't run `drush updb` throw an error

> The Pathauto module is not compatible with the current version of Drupal core. Update the [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to 8.x-1.6 or later.

Because it check on pathauto version in [system_requirements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/8.8.x)
and get the version as null:

```
$info = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getExtensionInfo('pathauto');
// This is null 
$info['version']
```

Composer version **1.9.1** .
My `composer.json`:

```
{
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Author",
      "email": "email@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Author 2",
      "email": "contact@somedomaine.fr"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Osinet\\Deploy\\": "scripts/Osinet/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ]
  },

  "config": {
    "discard-changes": true,
    "preferred-install": "source",
    "process-timeout": 3600,
    "secure-http": false,
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "description": "Project",
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
      "import": ["type:zend-extra"],
      "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
      "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
      "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
      "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
      "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"]
    },
    "osinet-builder": {
      "params": "settings/params.local.yml",
      "tmp-dir": "tmp"
    },
    "patches": {
      "drupal/media_entity": {
        "Fix broken route remote": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/dynamically_define_menu-2831071-17.patch"
      }
    },
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": false,
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/dawehner/drush_language.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/kgaut/drupal-potx.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.0.0",
    "ext-SPL": "*",
    "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
    "ext-Zend-OPcache": "*",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-date": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-filter": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-hash": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-pcre": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
    "ext-session": "*",
    "ext-tokenizer": "*",
    "ext-xml": "*",
    "lib-curl": "^7.36.0",
    "lib-iconv": "*",
    "lib-libxml": "*",
    "lib-openssl": "*",
    "lib-pcre": "*",
    "composer/installers": "^1.3",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.6.2",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.3",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.19",
    "drupal/advagg": "^4.0",
    "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.1",
    "drupal/autologout": "^1.0",
    "drupal/cdn": "3.x-dev",
    "drupal/ckeditor_iframe": "^2.0",
    "drupal/ckeditor_media_embed": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/color_field": "2.x-dev",
    "drupal/console": "^1.8.0",
    "drupal/core": "8.8.1",
    "drupal/crop": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/date_popup": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/draggableviews": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/drush_language": "dev-8.x-1.x",
    "drupal/eck": "^1.0",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.0-rc1",
    "drupal/entityqueue": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/fakeobjects": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0-beta1",
    "drupal/field_hidden": "^1.0",
    "drupal/file_version": "^1.0",
    "drupal/form_mode_manager": "2.x-dev",
    "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.1",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/jwt": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/maxlength": "1.0-beta4",
    "drupal/media_entity": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/media_entity_image": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/memcache": "2.x-dev",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4.0",
    "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "2.2",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.0",
    "drupal/pathauto": "1.6",
    "drupal/restui": "^1.17",
    "drupal/toolbar_menu": "^2.1",
    "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0",
    "drush/drush": "8.x-dev"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "^3.4",
    "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
    "composer/composer": "^1.5@dev",
    "doctrine/cache": "~1.6.2",
    "doctrine/collections": "~1.4.0",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.7.0",
    "doctrine/inflector": "~1.2.0",
    "doctrine/instantiator": "~1.0.5",
    "drupal/coder": "^8.2",
    "drupal/config_inspector": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/devel": "1.x-dev",
    "kgaut/potx": "8.x-1.x-dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.1",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.7.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
  },
  "type": "project"
}
```

Any ideas, will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `"preferred-install": "source"` from config or set it to `"dist"`.
 Putting `"source"` means Composer will get a package from a version control repository. And it seems to be downloading directly from https://git.drupalcode.org where all projects have no fixed version in their info files no matter which Git tag you check out.

You also can set more advanced patterns, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install. In your case it probably can be boiled down to the following.

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "drupal/*": "dist",
            "*": "source"
        }
    }
}
```

Then remove vendor/, remove the lock file and reinstall. `rm -rf vendor/ && rm composer.lock && composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer, you are getting Git checkouts due to the `"preferred-install": "source"` in the *composer.json* file. You could remove that (or replace the "source" value with "dist", although presumably you have that there for a reason).

To solve this problem, there is the [Composer Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_deploy) module, which augments Drupal's internal version information with information from composer's metadata. If you want to install from source *and* you want version information, this is the way to do it.